# MaraDNS fatal error

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm trying to run MaraDNS 2.0.13 on Windows 7 as an authoritative DNS over LAN. I am getting the following error when running maradns.exe with the command `maradns -f mararc`:

> Fatal error: No recursion in MaraDNS 2; use Deadwood
> ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=3.

I am already running Deadwood as recursive DNS and it appears to be working properly. Why does MaraDNS crash? Can I tell it that I am in fact using Deadwood?

Here is my `mararc` file.

```
ipv4_bind_addresses = "127.0.0.1, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
timestamp_type = 2
random_seed_file = "secret.txt"
recursive_acl = "192.168.1.0/24"

csv2 = {}
csv2["local.tld."] = "db.local.tld"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have older version of `mararc` file with unsupported option

`recursive_acl = "192.168.1.0/24"`

Remove this line from cfg and start service again, everything should work

Comment: Well that removed the error. Now I have to figure out why is has a `Problem binding to port 53.` Thanks.

Comment: I don't known this software in detail, but it looks like two separate programs and both can bind port 53. If you want authoritative server only, you can stop Deadwood server and release port 53 for MaraDNS

Comment: If I run MaraDNS before then it seems to be able to grab the port and Deadwood still seems to work. I have not been able to get a successful query for local.tld using askmara, even when only running the authoritative server. Thanks though.